the transition animation of the parent div not working when elements inside the div changes caused by Javascript
I'm making a file upload website. There are tables in the .form div and the button is used to submit. If the user's input is invalid, errors will show under the button.
The entire page was animated by myself smoothly, except the part where the error message pops under the button.
In my opinion, the div should slowly become higher and the new text shows as the div transforms. However after clicking the button, the <div> instantly changes its size, and there is no transition animations.
I tried setTimeout in JS and requestAnimationFrame, but neither of them worked. I can't use a pre-calculated height because the text may have multiple rows on different devices.
Please help me to solve it, thanks!


function expand() {
  let appender = $('#txt');
  appender.html("LONGERTEXT<br>HIGHERTEXT<br>more error messages");
}
.testbox {
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: transform 1s ease-out;
}

.form {
  min-height: 100%;
  max-width: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background: #00aeffd0;
  transition: transform 1s ease-out;
}
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<div class="testbox">
  <div class="form" style="width: 100%;">
    <button onclick="expand()">expand</button>
    <p id="txt"></p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>




it is just a demo so i uses a cdn randomly found by me. in the actual code it is up to date, as i have the latest ver on the server. ty for pointing out nevertheless!

transform from what to what? It has to have some value. You can't animate/transition to/from auto. You are basically populating the text element from nothing to something with no animation, it just pops in. You can't animate, essentially, display "nothing" to display "something".
I'd suggest hiding the #txt element then leverage Jquery's slideDown to show the element.


function expand() {
  let appender = $("#txt");
  appender.html("LONGERTEXT<br>HIGHERTEXT<br>more error messages");
  $("#txt").slideDown("slow", function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
}
.testbox {
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: transform 1s ease-out;
}

.form {
  min-height: 100%;
  max-width: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background: #00aeffd0;
  transition: transform 1s ease-out;
}

#txt {
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="testbox">
  <div class="form" style="width: 100%;">
    <button onclick="expand()">
                expand
            </button>
    <p id="txt">

    </p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>




thx! it's perfect! Lovin this community as a new user now!
